# Watching a StateNotifier doesn't catch the next state

Tags: flutter, dart, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I have this suffix icon:

```
  Widget suffixIcon(BuildContext context) {
    final isLoading = provider.watch(boolProvider);
    return isLoading
        ? SizedBox(
            width: SUFFIX_ICON_WIDTH_LENGTH,
            height: SUFFIX_ICON_HEIGHT_LENGTH,
            child: Stack(children: [
              Positioned(
                top: PAD_S,
                right: SUFFIX_ICON_PAD,
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark),
              )
            ]))
        : Container(width: 0);
  }
```

And this state notifier:

```
final boolProvider = StateNotifierProvider<BoolStateNotifier, bool>((provider) {
  return BoolStateNotifier(isLoading: false);
});

class BoolStateNotifier extends StateNotifier<bool> {
  BoolStateNotifier({required bool isLoading}) : super(isLoading);

  void setState(bool newState) {
    state = newState;
  }
}
```

I set the state like this:

```
  FutureOr<Iterable<Suggestion<TSuggestion>>> search(String input) async {
    if (input.isNotEmpty) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      provider.read(boolProvider.notifier).setState(true);
      });
      final results =
          (await repository.search(mapInputToSearchParams(input)))?.data;
      provider.read(boolProvider.notifier).setState(false);
```

The `provider.read(boolProvider.notifier).setState(false)` line does execute, but the suffix icon where I watch it does not catch the false, so the icon is showing forever. Any idea why? It only happens on the first search. It is used in a [flutter_typeahead](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_typeahead) `TypeAheadFormField` suffixIcon, so there is a fair bit of technology in there; I will try to extract it to a simple example.

Comment: false == false, so if you're trying to change from false to false, it rightfully doesn't nootify.  If you want to trigger on every call to setState, add ref.notifyListeners() in your notifier method.

Comment: Your constant naming does not comply with the [Effective Dart: Style guidelines](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/style#prefer-using-lowercamelcase-for-constant-names). Consider changing this.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz Am I setting it from false to false? The setting code is `provider.read(boolProvider.notifier).setState(true);` then this: `provider.read(boolProvider.notifier).setState(false)`. I'm confused.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz See bottom of question for attempt at your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Without something that we can execute, it's going to be hard to tell

Comment: @RémiRousselet I managed to simplify the code down, and something interesting I have noticed is that when I remove `.autoDispose`, it resolves this issue, the next state is correctly caught and the widget is rebuilt. There is something going on with the lifecycle of the provider when using `.autoDispose`, it seems to be disposed, causing the next state not to be listened to anymore. Is this expected behaviour?